# Why does float() not "unstring" a string formatted list element?

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I need to parse a comma delimited string that is part of a dict into values. I receive the data originally as a (huge) JSON formatted string and am loading it into a dict with `json.loads()`.

Some of the values split from the string will always be floats and I just want to float() those, while others can be either strings, null, or empty and will need to be treated separately (not the topic of this question).

Bizarrely, after splitting the string, the resulting list appears to contain some non-float()-able version of a string.

Consider this small python3 example code

```
# construct the sample dict
var = {}
var['abc'] = '"123.456","zzz"'

# JSONify it
var_json = json.dumps(var)

print("var_json: %s" % json.loads(var_json))

# var_json now exemplifies the input data
# deJSONify it:
data_in = json.loads(var_json)

a = data_in['abc'].split(",")
print(a[0])
print("this works:", float("123.456"))
print("this borks:", float(a[0]))
```

This results in the following output:

```
var_json: {'abc': '"123.456","456"'}
"123.456"
this works: 123.456
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 26, in <module>
    print("this borks:", float(a[0]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '"123.456"'
```

So: Clearly, to python the value in the list resulting from the split is a string (has double quotes around it in the output). But using `float()` on that string doesn't work.

Changing that last line to manually replace the quotes works:

```
print(float(a[0].replace("\"", "")))
```

So it looks like `a[0]` is in fact a string containing double quotes.

The same error occurs even without the json.dumps/loads roundtrip, e.g. just accessing the split list from the dict directly:

```
print("This also borks: ", float(var['abc'].split(",")[0]))
```

Why does float() not "unstring" what very clearly is a string and a valid float conversion input? How can I avoid that .replace() call?

Comment: The problem with `'"123.456"'` is the literal quotes on the inside. If it were `'123.456'` (with only syntactic quotes and no literal ones) it would be fine.

Comment: How to avoid having to remove the quotes? Don't put them in there in the first place.

Comment: Or if, say, your data is CSV on the inside, use the Python CSV module to decapsulate it after you've using `json.load()` to do the outer deserialization.

Comment: BTW, you don't need _any_ JSON steps to recreate this problem. `var = {'abc': '"123.456","zzz"'}; float(var['abc'].split(',')[0])` is enough.

Comment: ...heck, you don't even need the dict. `var='"123.456","zzz"'; float(var.split(',')[0])` will do as well.

Comment: (that said, it would have avoided this whole problem to use `{'abc': ["123.456", "456"]}`

Comment: Guys - read the question. The input format is a given - I only made up the input data to provide a working example. I can't "not put them in there" as Kelly suggest, or change the input format, Charles. But thanks for the hint with the syntactic vs literal quotes.

Comment: That's what it sounded like, yes. So the suggestion is to tell whoever does put them in there to not do that. Or to ask them how they intend you to parse it. In my opinion **always** the wrong approach to guess or ask random others. The people providing data want the data to be usable, so they're the ones to ask.

Comment: The input is from a legacy system that nobody wants to touch. My solution only intended to bridge the days until it falls over and finally croaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not enough to just split on commas; you also need to remove the literal quotation marks from the content of the string.

Quotation marks are not numbers. Thus, a string that contains quotation marks *as part of the data within it* is not a string that contains only a number. Just as the Python string `'a123a'` cannot be parsed as a number, neither can `'"123"'`: The `"`s are just as out-of-place in the second example as the `a`s are in the first.

For example, you could use:

```
float(a[0].replace('"', ''))
```

---

Insofar as your JSON document is encapsulating CSV data, you can use the Python `csv` module to parse it in a way that will remove those quotes:

```
data_in = {'abc': '"123.456","zzz"'}
a = csv.reader([data_in['abc']]).__next__()
print("this now works:", float(a[0]))
```

Comment: That's an interesting option, thanks @CharlesDuffy.